# I am trying to make a function that checks whether all characters in a string are unique, and returns 0 if this is so, or 1 if not all are unique

Tags: c, char, unique, cs50, c-strings

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. It just seems to print 0 most of the time, when I change string word. Would appreciate any help/comments - is it a problem with the logic in my code? If so, where, and how can I rectify it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_unique_letters(string words);

int main (void)
{
    string word =  "ABCB" ;
    printf ("%i\n", check_unique_letters (word));
}


int check_unique_letters (string words)
{
    int j = 0;
    
    do
    {   int x = (int) (words [j]) ;
        int y = 0;
        for (int i=j + 1; i<strlen(words); i++)
        {
            if ((int)words[i] == x)
            {
                y += 1;
            }
            
            else
            {
                y+= 0;
            }
        }
        
        if (y>0)
        {
            return 1;
            break;
        }
        
        else
        {
            j = j+1;
        }
        
    }
    while (j < strlen (words));
}
```

Comment: If the outer `do .. while` loop ends, what do you return then?

Comment: don't use `strlen` in a condition test - in this case it turns a nominally O(n^2) algorithm into O(n^4). Get the length once and store it in a variable

Comment: @Alnitak Your advice is generically sound, but here getting the length once and storing it in a variable turns what should be an O(1) algorithm into O(n). Better here is to store `strnlen(words, UCHAR_MAX+1)` in a variable (perhaps writing the equivalent of strnlen yourself because it's not standard C). Any string longer than UCHAR_MAX will have a duplicate in the first UCHAR_MAX+1 characters.

Comment: @PaulHankin `words` is the input string, not an array of found vs not-found flags.  Without such an array the algorithm is always O(n^2)

Comment: @Alnitak here's an O(1) version of this code: https://gist.github.com/paulhankin/363629b0eb731db3b60a1a40deaebfd2 . The same code with `strlen` instead of `strnlen` is O(n).

Comment: @PaulHankin that code is worst case O(n^2), not O(1) - it has two nested loops each of length proportional to the input string's length.

Comment: @Alnitak No, it has two nested loops each of length at most 257 (UCHAR_MAX+2).

Comment: albeit with `n` constrained to `UCHAR_MAX` typical value of 255.

Comment: it's still worse case O(n^2) within that range, but the observation that any duplicate must occur within the first UCHAR_MAX characters is indeed useful.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns nothing outside the do-while loop though its return type is not void.

That is after the do-while loop you need to place the statement

```
return 0;
```

Pay attention to that there is no need to use objects of the type int like

```
int x = (int) (words [j]) ;
```

and there is a redundant code that does not have an effect like this else

```
        else
        {
            y+= 0;
        }
```

or like the break statement

```
    if (y>0)
    {
        return 1;
        break;
    }
```

And it would be more logically consistent if the function returned non-zero in case when all symbols are unique.

Also calling the function strlen is inefficient.

I would write the function the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_unique_letters( const char *s )
{
    if (*s)
    {
        while (s[1] != '\0' && strchr( s + 1, *s ) == NULL) ++s;
    }

    return *s == '\0' || s[1] == '\0';
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "ABCB";

    printf( "All characters of the string \"%s\" are %s.\n",
            s, check_unique_letters( s ) ? "unique" : "not unique" );

    s = "ABCD";

    printf( "All characters of the string \"%s\" are %s.\n",
            s, check_unique_letters( s ) ? "unique" : "not unique" );
}
```

The program output is

```
All characters of the string "ABCB" are not unique.
All characters of the string "ABCD" are unique.
```

Comment: @Alnitak The function strcmp returns one of three values (negative, zero, or positive). In case of the function in the question then it answers to the question either "yes" or "no".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick implementation of what you need. You can quickly compare as to where you might be going wrong.
Feel free to modify the program to suit your needs.

You can see it running [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kjgwClIfyOZvtDFm).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_unique_chars(char* str, int length)
{
// standard null checks
    if (length == 0 || str == NULL)
        return 1;
// The easiest way to do this is to, for each character
// compare every other character ahead of it. If there is a match, then return 1. Else return 0.
    for(int idx =0; idx < length; ++idx)
    {
        for(int idx1 =idx+1; idx1 < length; ++idx1)
        {
            if (str[idx] == str[idx1])
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char* s = "Hel0";
    char* s1 = "banana";
    printf("string has unique chars: %s\n", check_unique_chars(s, strlen(s)) == 0 ? "true" : "false");
    printf("string has unique chars: %s\n", check_unique_chars(s1, strlen(s1)) == 0 ? "true" : "false");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am reasonably sure this is not the most efficient implementation, but it is quite obvious in its operation and you should be able to modify it to suit your needs.